# F# SqlEntityConnection Works on Azure, Does Not Work on SqlExpress

Tags: entity-framework, f#, type-providers

I am using the SqlEntityConnection type provider using F# using the following code and .config file:

Code:

```
type internal SqlConnection = SqlEntityConnection<ConnectionStringName="azureData">

type public RestaurantAnalysis () =

    let connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings.["azureData"].ConnectionString;

    member public x.GetAverageScoreByMonth () =
        SqlConnection.GetDataContext(connectionString).Restaurants
```

.Config:

```
<add name="azureData" connectionString="data source=tcp:xxxxx;
     initial catalog=RestaurantChicken;persist security info=True;
     user id=xxxx;password=xxxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"/>
```

This is working great.  But when I spin up the same database locally, I am running into a problem.  I created a a new entry in the .config file:

```
<add name="localData" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;
     initial catalog=RestaurantChicken;persist security info=True;
     Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"/>
```

When I compile, I get this exception:

*The field, constructor or member 'Restaurants' is not defined*

And when I look at design time, only the 'Connection' and 'DataContext' is available via
SqlConnection.GetDataContext(connectionString).

I am wondering if some kind of permissions need to be set on the local database so that the tp can inspect the tables to do it's type definition.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello, did you manage to find an answer to this?

Comment: There was EF magic going on.  EF assumes a local database, even if you don't want it to. :-(

Comment: Thanks. That's what I found. I only actually needed a single string result so went with a normal SQL connection and a text query.

Answer (score 0):

In config connection name is "localData", in code is "azureData".
May, in this case?

Consider using a single name in all cases.

Comment: No, in the code it is changed to localData.  I just didn't show it.